# Sending email automatically based on time elapsed

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, cron

I am working on an API at the moment, and we are just starting work on the notification centre. One of the things that I am wanting to implement is that if a user has a notification that is unread and older than 1 hour old, then they get an email sent to them.

I cannot work out how I would wrap this in a CRON job on my server though to catch all possible timinings? Would I need to run something every minute? And if I do if this not quite labour intensive for the server? Would I be better handing it off to a queuning service that keeps it in queue until it is read, and after an hour sends an email?

Comment: Not an answer but this link could help: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling